# Django. Paginate a @link or @action method of Viewset

Tags: python, django, pagination

I'm developing a API Restful using Django Restframework and DRF Extensions.

I have the next Viewset of User

```
class UserViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_class = conversation.UserFilter

    @link(is_for_list=True)
    def favorites(self,request,pk=None):
        """Return the profile of the user"""
        fav = UserFavorite.objects.filter(user=request.user, is_favorite=True)
        favorites = UserFavoriteReadOnlySerializer(fav,many=True)
        return Response(favorites.data)
```

And Settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
...
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': (
    'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination'
),
...
```

I want to get on the response of this method the applied pagination, however does not return what I want 'cause returns all objects associated with the search method without pagination.

As I can turn the pagintion for this method?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [DRF docs for PageNumberPagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination), you'll see that you need to include a `'PAGE_SIZE'` key-value pair to set the number of pages that are returned.

For example, your pagination settings should look like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
    ...
}
```

Comment: Right, and I have it in my settings but I don't put it above this @jonathan-cox